# Declaring filters in application config

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to add a filter into an application config, but there is little documentation about this issue. I have managed to call a filter through the behaviour definition in the web.php like:

```
  'as derp' => [
        'class' => 'RouteToMyFilter',
        'only' => ['url/defined'],
 ],
```

I am using, as suggested in the note in this url: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-filters.html

*Note: When declaring filters in modules or applications, you should use routes instead of action IDs in the only and except properties. This is because action IDs alone cannot fully specify actions within the scope of a module or application.*

But, as you see (the url it's stupid, I know, but, it's for testing purpouses only), I have defined a route but the library it's using the id of the active controller, ignoring any route. Is there any way to define a filter to make it use the routes or the note it's wrong?